# TypeError when I try to run my app simulator at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/

Tags: react-native

When I try to run my app simulator with react-native run-android, the application starts normally, but the debugger at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ doesn't show console.log and print this error :

```
(index):92 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'volume' of null
at Object.render ((index):92)
at Object.setState ((index):46)
at WebSocket.ws.onopen ((index):152)
```

Comment: You forgot to add code that causes this error. Or maybe is it question about debugger-ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try opening the `In - App Developer Menu`

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu

Next click `Debug JS Remotely`.